# drag and drop a box from one div to many divs

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I would like to drg n drop a div with width 60px (ccarcellbook) onto 3 divs with width 20px (ccarcell).
Have got basic d n d function so that the big div replaces one of small divs,
but dont know how to replace 3 small divs

jquery

```
$('.ccarcellbook').draggable({
  helper:"clone",
  cursor: "move",
  snap:'.ccarcell', 
  snapMode:'inner'
});
$('.ccarcell').droppable({
  over: function(event, ui) {var $this = $(this)},
  drop:function(event, ui) {
  ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

html

```
<div class="ccarcell"></div>
<div class="ccarcell"></div>
<div class="ccarcell"></div>
<div class="ccarcellbook>DRAG ME</div>
<div class="ccarcell"></div>
<div class="ccarcell"></div>
<div class="ccarcell"></div>
```

any advice welcome

Comment: also if I drop "ccarcellbook" onto 3 "ccarcell" the div id returned by alert($(this).attr('id')); is the middle div. Any ideas how to return the first div id of the three?

Comment: Hi, plz see http://jsfiddle.net/zima101/UxfNX/1/
when you move car1 onto first "ccarcell id=2_1" the id returned is "2_2"
how do i get id of first div "2_1"